# calling recursive callback within function returning promise

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, promise

I've got a function that appends nodes to the dom and if the node is a script tag with "src" attribute it will set an eventlistener for the "load" event and the callback is the same function so when the js tag will finish executing the same function will be called again and continue to append the nodes exactly where it left of (using document fragment)
pseudo code example:

```
function appender(){// i'm calling the function with bind so 'this' is my object
while(documentfragment.children.length > 0){
if(scriptwithsrc){
node.addeventlistener("load",appender.bind(this));
parentnode.appendchild(node);
return;
}
//if its not a script tag than just append the node
parentnode.appendchild(node);

return Promise.resolve();
```

Now I've got another func the "main" one which executes this func.
and I'm using "then" to continue execution after the `appender` func has finished.
pseudo code example:

```
let appenderBinder = appender.bind(Myobject);
Myobject.fragment = fragment1;
appenderBinder().then(() => {
//first execution for fragment1 is over lets continue to fragment2
//we call it again but change our object before that
Myobject.fragment = fragment2;
appenderBinder().then(() => {
//some more code
})})
```

the problem is that if the fragment contains a script tag with src the function will just return; and not return a promise so I'm getting

"`Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`",

but I need to use return in order to exit the function and wait for the callback to execute it again and continue appending from the same spot, and only after it finishes appending every node than the promise should return and the ".then()" should be executed.
any ideas?

Comment: It is my opinion that what you are doing here is not an appropriate way to handle this. It is fixable, but even with a fix it will not be the right way to handle this. To fix this, you need to return a promise when you have a script as well, but you need to return and unresolved promise, which then gets "resolved" once the load event fires. Read more on how to do that here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Creating_a_Promise

Comment: @Dellirium First thanks a lot for your reply, indeed i can create a promise and use promise.all to return when all promises returns and the function finished appending everything , but when a script tag is encountered i need to wait for the load event to fire before continue appending and i just can't see how to implement this because i need to wait for the previous promise to resolve before continuing and than after all promises resolve to return promise.all to the main func

Comment: Let me verify I understand you correctly, say you have a promise chain that handles fragments A, B, C and D, say fragment B has a script tag. This tag gets loaded and after the load you want to simply continue onto the C and D or do you want to do something else like, idk load an X which was not in the initial chain?

Comment: @Dellirium let me explain in details : lets say i've got a fragment with 10 nodes , so the "appender" starts appending each node (we need to maintain the order , it's crucial with js tags) and we encounter a js tag so we bind to the load event , at that point we need to wait for the js to execute and the load event to fire so we can continue appending the nodes

Comment: I've added an answer with an explanation below, however, do note that you are using a `while` in your code and have not closed the while tag in the post. It is due to this reason that I have no bothered with "referencing" the `while` part of the code, but it logically would have to close it's block before doing a regular `return Promise.all()` which I assume is the goal here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> only after it finishes appending every node than the promise should return

No, you will need to create and return the promise immediately. The promise should be *fulfilled* when you are done appending all nodes. So you would write

```
function appender() {
  if (documentfragment.children.length > 0){
    if (scriptwithsrc) {
      const promise = new Promise(resolve => {
//                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
        node.addeventlistener("load", resolve);
//                                    ^^^^^^^
        parentnode.appendchild(node);
      });
      return promise.then(appender.bind(this));
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    } else { // its not a script tag then just append the node
      parentnode.appendchild(node);
      return appender.call(this); // recurse
    }
  } else {
    return Promise.resolve();
  }
}
```

Comment: it does maintain the order right? and the "then" in the main function will execute only when appender() will finish appending everything right?

Comment: @avidahan Yes, `then()` returns another promise for the result of the callback

Comment: Simple and elegant , Perfect!

Comment: How do you avoid calling the appender twice for a single node? Like, if you run into a script tag, you would return the `promise.then(appender.bind(this))` but since this is something that was iterated half way through, it would just start from start and result in an endless loop once it reaches the same script tag again, what am I missing?

Comment: @Dellirium Why would it start over from the beginning? Your pseudo code doesn't show where you are getting the `node` from, but I assume you would remove it from the `documentfragment` so that it is getting emptied during the recursive evaluation. This shouldn't be any different between the script and non-script cases.

Comment: @Bergi i missed the fact that we are talking about document fragment, treated it as if it was any array of elements.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from mozzila's MDN :

> A Promise object is created using the new keyword and its constructor. This constructor takes as its argument a function, called the "executor function". This function should take two functions as parameters. The first of these functions (resolve) is called when the asynchronous task completes successfully and returns the results of the task as a value. The second (reject) is called when the task fails, and returns the reason for failure, which is typically an error object.

Accompanied by this code example:

```
const myFirstPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
// do something asynchronous which eventually calls either:
//
//   resolve(someValue); // fulfilled
// or
//   reject("failure reason"); // rejected
});
```

**So how does this apply to your question:**

You want to interrupt a promise chain if you run into a script tag, in which case you want to wait for it to load first, before continuing to go down the chain. In order to do this, you need to change your code a bit.

```
if(scriptwithsrc){
  node.addeventlistener("load",appender.bind(this));
  parentnode.appendchild(node);
  return; //This line here is the problem
}
```

The above code is taken from your post and is being run synchronously, and what you are doing is, you are returning no value. Since you do not return a promise, your function cannot be used in a then-able promise chain. What you need to do instead is this:

```
if(scriptwithsrc){
  let loadingDone = new Promise(function(res, rej){
    node.addEventListener("load", res)
    parentnode.appendchild(node)
  }
  return loadingDone; // This line returns the promise as usual
}
else{
  parentnode.appendchild(node)
  return Promise.resolve() //And so does this line
}
```

Once the script tag loads, it will trigger the `res` function which will resolve the promise and your chain will continue. In this particular case the **something asynchronous** part of the mozzila's code example refers to the loading of your script tag.

EDIT: Since it was not very clear from the initial post, and was later clarified in the comments, the chain needs to continue from whence it stopped in the current fragment, so as per request a working example was added to reflect this.

**Working example:**

```js
function appender(arg) {
    let i;
    for (i = 0; i < arg.length; i++) {
        if (arg[i].script) {
            let chainedPromise;
            let pauseProm = new Promise(function (res, rej) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    console.log('Appended element: ', arg[i].name);
                    res();
                }, 2000); //to mimic script load;
            });
            let j;
            let newChain = [];
            for (j = i + 1; j < arg.length; j++) {
                newChain.push(arg[j]);
            }
            chainedPromise = pauseProm.then(function () {
                return appender(newChain)
            });
            return chainedPromise;
        } else
            console.log('Appended element: ', arg[i].name);
    }
    return Promise.resolve();
}

function Main() {
    appender([
        {name: '1', script: false},
        {name: '2', script: false},
        {name: '3', script: true}
    ]).then(function () {
        appender([
            {name: '4', script: false},
            {name: '5', script: false},
            {name: '6', script: true},
            {name: '7', script: true}
        ]).then(function () {
            appender([
                {name: '8', script: false},
                {name: '9', script: true},
                {name: '10', script: false},
                {name: '11', script: true},
                {name: '12', script: true}
            ]).then(function () {
                console.log('done')
            });
        });
    });
}
Main();
```

Comment: that's not exactly what i need because as you can see in my "main" function i'm using "then" to execute more code when the entire func operation has finished and by that i mean appending everything. in your example i'm returning a promise that will be resolve when the script tag will fire the load event, and what about all the other nodes after the script tag? i can use promise.all to resolve when all promises resolve but i still need to maintain the order and wait for each promise to resolve before continuing to the next one

Comment: The chain would continue as it would as if no script tag was found, the only thing happens is a `pause` in the code execution. The `.then` in the main function would still fire appropriately since the promise chain would continue.

Comment: first in my example the "return promise.resolve" is outside of the while loop  sorry for that its just an example.
and your right if i will use promise.all and just push to an array all the promises and resolve when they done the "then" in the main func will execute but that's not what i need because lets say i've encounter a script tag and i will push the promise to our array and continue the loop , than most likely that the node after the script tag will be appended before the script tag event fires and thats not good i need to maintain the order

Comment: I know that when all promises resolve the main will continue to execute the "then" code , that's not my problem. my problem is that i need to maintain the order of nodes so what i actually need is to wait for each promise to resolve before pushing the next one and after every promise resolve than return promise.all and continue executing the "then" in the main func

Comment: Okay so that was not clear from your question, let me edit my answer to reflect that

Comment: Your example does work but @Bergi solution is much more simpler and elegant , nonetheless thanks a lot for your help

Comment: No problem m8, I did not understand what you wanted to do at first, if you take a look at just the appender function, you will notice there is not much difference between the two answers. I am actually not certain that his answer will work since I do not see how he makes sure that you do not run over same element twice, nor do I see how he iterates over multiple elements (there is no loop there) but if it works, great!

Comment: you are right but you probably missed the fact that I’m using document fragment and if you will check the spec you will see that document fragment acts a lot like the real dom and when I’m doing appendchild the element “transferred” from the document fragment to the dom so on each function call the document.fragment.length is actually decreasing until no element remains :)

Comment: @avidahan you are correct, I missed that, treated it as if you were passing an array. This could have made it simpler indeed